# Probability of having balls of only two colors

Tags: combinatorics

In a box there are two white balls, two green balls and two red balls. If we choose four balls without replacement, what is the probability of having balls of only two colors?

The answer is $1/30$ but I didn't understand why.

Comment: The answer isn't $1/30$.

Comment: Well...if we label the balls as $W_1,W_2,G_1,G_2,R_1,R_2$ there are $\binom 64 = 15$ ways to choose your four balls.  Exactly three of those ways have only two colors, so I see the answer as $\frac 3{15}=\frac 15$.  Assuming of course that each ball is equally likely to be chosen.

Comment: @lulu but isn't better to label $W,W,G,G,R,R$?

Comment: I labeled the balls to make it clear that each combination was equi-probable.  There are situations in which that is important.  Possibly not here, but as the answer you provide seems so obviously incorrect I thought it was worth being explicit.

Comment: Just to be clear, the problem with your labeling is that it makes it look like choosing the pair $WG$ is as probable as choosing the pair $WW$, but it isn't.  There are four ways to choose $WG$ and only one way to choose $WW$.  However, choosing the pair $W_1G_1$ has exactly the same probabilty as choosing the pair $W_1W_2$.

Comment: I got your point. However, using your label we would have $W_1G_1\neq W_2G_2$, but they are the same one white ball and one green ball.

Comment: Sure, you can interpret those as being the same pair in the end, no problem.   But having equiprobable events at the start makes everything a simple matter of counting.

Comment: Same as with tossing a pair of dice.  It's useful to imagine that the dice are distinguished in order to compute all the probabilities, even if in the end you only care about the unordered pair.  Thus the roll $\{1,2\}$ has twice the probability of the roll $\{1,1\}$ as the former includes the two ordered rolls $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$.

Comment: To do it your way:  note that choosing four is the same as choosing two.  The probability that the second selection has the same color as the first is obviously $\frac 15$ as there are five balls left and only one of the appropriate color.  Thus, the answer is still $\frac 15$.

Comment: You just asked this question a few minutes ago.

Comment: @lulu I turned our comments in a question.

Comment: In the comments to the first posting of this question, I explained how to solve the problem without distinguishing the balls so you clearly don't "have to" label the balls one way or the other.

Comment: @user42912 hey, don't ask the same question twice ... you have 8 thousand points you know how this place works no excuse for this nonsense

Comment: The event of "one white and one green" is the set of outcomes $\{W_1G_1, W_1G_2, W_2G_1, W_2G_2\}$.  Removing the label may make the green balls indistinguishable, however, it does not make them identical -- they remain discrete objects.

Comment: @lulu I'm sorry, as I said above our comments give my an extra doubt that I found useful to turned into a question.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I think I got your point, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pick balls of only 2 colors you have 3 different possible pairs of color (white-green, white-red or red-green). Then let us look at the probability of having 2 red and 2 green balls: it is $$\dfrac{{2 \choose 2}{2 \choose 2}{2 \choose 0}  }{6 \choose 4}=\dfrac{1}{15}$$

Finally since you have 3 possible configurations of this probability you get $$3 \dfrac{1}{15}=\dfrac{1}{5}$$

Comment: did you mean $\binom{6}{4}$ in the denominator?

Comment: yes, of course sorry. And I used the fact that ${6 \choose 4}={6 \choose 2}$ in my head to compute it...

Comment: Thank you. I have another doubt. How did you get the denominator $\binom{6}{4}$? did you call the balls as distinct ones such as $W_1,W_2,G_1,G_2,R_1,R_2$? I'm confused because the balls of the same colors are essentially the same.

Comment: yes you have to choose 4 balls out of 6. It is true that 2 white balls are similar but they are different. You have to label them distinctly to get the result. Indeed if you have 4 balls, 2 green and 2 white (for example after having picked 2 red balls), you have 4 times more chances to pick 1 white and 1 green than picking 2 white.

Comment: And btw imagine you write behind each ball (ok behind a ball is not clear but yeah) its label. You can do the exercise with labelled balls (then different from each other) and this won't change the result

Comment: I think I got your point, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter which of the two white balls you choose - what matters is that you have one white ball and one green ball. So, the second of your two labels is the better one.

---

In order for the four balls you choose to have only two colors, the two balls that you don't chose must be of the same color.

There are $$\binom{6}{2} = 15$$ ways to choose the two balls that get left out of your chosen $4$. Of these sets of two, only $3$ are of a single color: $WW$, $GG$, and $RR$.

The probability that we completely leave out one of the three colors is therefore

$$\frac{3}{15} = \boxed{\frac{1}{5}}$$

Comment: So is this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2311443/42912 wrong?

Comment: @user42912 I got the same answer, with a different reasoning (see my edit), so I'd say the final answer $1/5$ is almost certainly correct.

Comment: I didn't understand why $\binom{6}{2}$.It seems you are calling the balls as $W_1,W_2,G_1,G_2,R_1,R_2$.

Comment: The balls remain discrete objects whether labeled or not, @user42912 .